# Colorbox across browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, colorbox

Does anyone please tell me the colorbox availability across different browsers ?

When I try to do so in Internet Explorer or Safari, the modal window does not open the BBB client. Instead it takes me to the BBB demo page on my BBB server. And I cannot seem to join even the BBB demo in the modal window. But it gets worse. I have added debugging code to make sure that the url being used in the modal window to call the BBB client is correct. If I simply take this URL and put it into a new tab in Internet Explorer or Safari, then the BBB client opens as expected. It just does not seem to be doing so in the modal window.